# How to get past No Man's Sky "snake bug"?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've rebooted the game a few times now and each time I start a save I end up in what I can only describe as a version of snake. It shows a map like screen with symbols spread out, one of which is a spaceship I can move around. It will go down if I press Ⓐ or further any direction if I use the right thumb stick, leaving a trail like the old Microsoft mouse when it crashed. I can hear the sounds of the spaceship and NPCs but I can't see them. Also if I go into the inventory by pressing back, when I come out of that it shows red lines spread over the screen. As I move the red lines gradually disappear by being covered by the trail of the spaceship.

I don't know if this is just part of the game and I'm missing something, but when looking for a fix I couldn't find anything referencing my problem.

**Microsoft like trail:**
[image: ScreenShot 1]

**Back button overlay:**
[image: back button overlay]

Comment: Can you provide of screenshot of the bug you are experiencing?

Comment: These issues sound graphical in nature, I would start by updating your graphics drivers. Other than that, a screenshot would really help here.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. I've yet to find any reference to this bug anywhere on the web (including page 2 of google), so it might be centralized to your PC. Per @Flater's comment, I would suggest updating your graphic drivers.

Comment: Are you console or PC using a game-pad?

Comment: @Malco Given the use of an Xbox controller, I'd say PC. No Man's Sky wasn't released on Microsoft consoles AFAIK.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Good point, OP should probably add PC tag then, as this looks like a graphics card error to me. Amadeus, do you have similar issues/strangeness in other games?

Comment: Console tags should only be used when referring to a feature of the game specific to that console. This glitch didn't happen during a PC-specific feature, so the tag is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

That definitely sounds like a graphics card/graphics driver problem. It seems like the frame buffer isn't properly updating. I've had very similar issues with other graphic-intensive games, and it's always either been faulty hardware, or an outdated driver. If you've recently updated your drivers, consider backing out to a previous working version.